# BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'fileName' available as request attribute " while trying to update a raw in my db,

Tags: jpa, controller, thymeleaf

I'm getting this exception while trying to update a row in my database. I performed a lot of research in Google all I find is that I should add @modelAttribute which is already done.

I also found that I need to add bindind result after @ModelAttribute but this also didn't work so I removed it. I'm using JPA for persistence to manipulate my data, spring boot and thymeleaf for my views.

1. These are my Controllers one for updating and rendering views

   ```
       @GetMapping("/edit/{id}")
      public ModelAndView UpdateList(@PathVariable(name="id") String id) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("updateList");
    com.pfe.ClientRest.model.Files files = fileServ.get(id);
    mav.addObject("Files", files);
    return mav ;
    }    
    @PostMapping("/Save")
    public String saveRepport(@ModelAttribute("Files") com.pfe.ClientRest.model.Files dbfile) {

    fileServ.save(dbfile);



    return "/redirect:/ListFile";
    }
   ```
2. this is my entity class I have getter setters and constructors

   ```
   @Table( name="Files")
   @Entity
   public class Files {
   @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
   @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
   @Id
   private String id;
   private String FileName;
   private String Verif;
   public String getId() {
   return id;
   }
   ```

this is my template.

```
     <div class="container">
     <h1> Modifier les informations du Rapports</h1>
     <form action="#" th:action="@{/Save}" th:objects="${Files}"  
     method="post" >
     <input type="text" th:field=*{id} readonly="readonly"/>
     <input type="text" th:field="*{fileName}" placeholder="Nom du Fichier" 
     class="form-control mb-4 
     col-4">
     <input type="text" th:field="*{verif}" placeholder="Accepted/Rejected" 
     class="form-control mb-4 
     col-4">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info col-2"> Mettre à jour</button>
    </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: yes thank you , but I still get the same exception

Answer (score 0):

The field names in the html page and entity class does not match. These are case sensitive. So the correct one should be

```
private String fileName;
private String verif;
```